# Reusing Django Changelist Outside of Admin Site

Tags: django, django-admin, changelist

The Django changelist table is really cool - searchable, filterable, multi-select actions etc.

I'm building a custom backend for an app and I keep realizing: this is exactly what I need, I should re-use it.

Has anyone had any experience using the change list outside of Django's admin app?

What I've arrived at currently is something like this:

```
from profile.admin import ProfileAdmin
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite
from profile.models import Profile
profile_admin = ProfileAdmin(Profile, AdminSite())
return profile_admin.changelist_view(request)
```

I'd like to know if anyone has had experience with this or can suggest an alternative.

Comment: Did you manage to reuse the Changelist or adapt it somehow?

Comment: Trying to do the same thing, would love to hear the end approach

Answer (score 9):

ChangeList as a class is really cool and feature-full. However, it's **hard to use** outside the context of the AdminSite monolith.

The ChangeList class takes 12 required `__init__()` parameters. That number alone should steer you away and doubly so when you realize those are all sourced from the Admin `changelist_view()`. While those parameters have remained the same since Django 1.1, they did change from 1.0 and it's so much a Django internal object, I wouldn't rely on its interface being stable.

The best way to use ChangeList — or specifically to get the *changelist benefits* (which is what you are after) — is to use the `changelist_view()` method. Using that of course requires using/subclassing AdminSite. **This is worth doing, or at least trying out.** Looks like you already are.

That method takes the `request` parameter and likes `/(?P<app_label>%s)/(?P<model_name>%s)/` in the URL route that points to it.

Digging into the code:

- `ChangeList` lives in `django.contrib.admin.views.main`
- `changelist_view()` is a method on `django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin`

**UPDATE:** In Django 1.4, both `ChangeList` and `changelist_view()` changed by adding one and two new parameters respectively.