# Delete multiple objects in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to delete all objects in my table. Is possible to have a request "
http://localhost:8000/api/products/delete_all/ " and when i do a get request i delete all objects.
I saw this solution [Delete multiple objects in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143262/delete-multiple-objects-in-django) but i don't know if is possible to implement this in a moldeViewSet.

**Views.py**

```
class ProductModelViews(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        permission_classes  =(permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
        queryset = ProductModel.objects.all()
        serializer_class = TestProductModelSerializer
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution

```
class ProductModelViews(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        permission_classes  =(permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
        queryset = ProductModel.objects.all()
        serializer_class = TestProductModelSerializer

        @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
        def delete_all(self, request):
                Product.objects.all().delete()
                return Response('success')
```