# Using ModelAdmin subsclass in my application

Tags: django, django-admin

I have added filtering, sorting, and searching to a ModelAdmin class named  AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin).  It works fantastic in the Django Admin application but I would like to display the change_list and add Albums in my application using AlbumAdmin.  I cannot find any information or an example on how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so you want the admin changelist view somewhere else in your application?

Comment: if yes, here may be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315500/reusing-django-changelist-outside-of-admin-site

Comment: @doniyor - thanks very much.  please move to an answer so I can give you the credit.

Comment: glad that it helped, but since there is already an answer there, no need to repeat it I think. better upvote that question and answer :) good luck!